# Sum values from one df base on two columns of another df

Tags: r, for-loop

These are subsets of two dataframes.

I have a df1 with measurements of degree_days each day along the year for each plot:

| date | plot | degree_days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5-13-19 | 1 | 3.5 |
| 5-13-19 | 2 | 5.35 |
| 5-13-19 | 3 | 4.8 |
| 5-14-19 | 1 | 4.5 |
| 5-14-19 | 2 | 4.4 |
| 5-14-19 | 3 | 5.8 |
| 5-15-19 | 1 | 3.5 |
| 5-15-19 | 2 | 5.35 |
| 5-15-19 | 3 | 4.8 |
| 5-16-19 | 1 | 4.5 |
| 5-16-19 | 2 | 4.4 |
| 5-16-19 | 3 | 5.8 |

(cont.)

And a df2 with dates of mean first flower in each plot:

| mean_first_flower_date | plot |
| --- | --- |
| 5-16-19 | 1 |
| 8-5-19 | 2 |
| 6-12-19 | 3 |
| 5-16-19 | 1 |
| 8-5-19 | 2 |
| 6-12-19 | 3 |
| 5-16-19 | 1 |
| 8-5-19 | 2 |
| 6-12-19 | 3 |

(cont.)

My goal is to use df1 to create a new variable in df2 that will sum degree_days up to the mean_first_flower_date in each plot. For example, if in df2, mean_first_flower_date was 5-16-19 in plot 1, then the new variable is 16 (i.e., sum of 3.5 + 4.5+ 3.5 + 4.5)"

| mean_first_flower_date | plot | new_var |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5-16-19 | 1 | 16 |

I tried this for-loop but I don't know how to condition the sum based on each plot:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df2)) {
    df2[i, "mean_first_flower_date"] -> flower 
    print(i)
    df1[df1$date <= flower, ] -> df1.temporary 
    sum(df1.temporary$degree_days) -> new_var 
    df2[i, "new_var"] <- new_var 
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R option by defining a user function `f` (thank @akrun's data)

```
f <- function(d, p) with(subset(df1, date <= d & plot == p), sum(degree_days))

dfout <- within(
  df2,
  new_var <- Vectorize(f)(mean_first_flower_date, plot)
)
```

such that

```
> dfout
  mean_first_flower_date plot new_var
1             2019-05-16    1    16.0
2             2019-08-05    2    19.5
3             2019-06-12    3    21.2
4             2019-05-16    1    16.0
5             2019-08-05    2    19.5
6             2019-06-12    3    21.2
7             2019-05-16    1    16.0
8             2019-08-05    2    19.5
9             2019-06-12    3    21.2
```

Answer (score 1):

A non-equi join would be useful after converting the 'date' columns to `Date` class

```
library(data.table)
new_var <- setDT(df1)[df2, sum(degree_days), on =
         .(plot, date <= mean_first_flower_date), by = .EACHI]$V1
setDT(df2)[, new_var := new_var][]
```

-output

```
df2
#   mean_first_flower_date plot new_var
#1:             2019-05-16    1    16.0
#2:             2019-08-05    2    19.5
#3:             2019-06-12    3    21.2
#4:             2019-05-16    1    16.0
#5:             2019-08-05    2    19.5
#6:             2019-06-12    3    21.2
#7:             2019-05-16    1    16.0
#8:             2019-08-05    2    19.5
#9:             2019-06-12    3    21.2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(date = c("5-13-19", "5-13-19", "5-13-19", "5-14-19", 
"5-14-19", "5-14-19", "5-15-19", "5-15-19", "5-15-19", "5-16-19", 
"5-16-19", "5-16-19"), plot = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), degree_days = c(3.5, 5.35, 4.8, 4.5, 4.4, 5.8, 
3.5, 5.35, 4.8, 4.5, 4.4, 5.8)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))

df2 <- structure(list(mean_first_flower_date = c("5-16-19", "8-5-19", 
"6-12-19", "5-16-19", "8-5-19", "6-12-19", "5-16-19", "8-5-19", 
"6-12-19"), plot = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))

df1$date <- as.Date(df1$date, "%m-%d-%y")
df2$mean_first_flower_date <- as.Date(df2$mean_first_flower_date, "%m-%d-%y")
```